# How to use pandas to check daily tick data in a monthly tick data csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a monthly tick data to analyze, which is like this:

```
Time (UTC),Ask,Bid,AskVolume,BidVolume
2007.04.01 21:00:47.593,95.203,95.159,19.1,8.8
2007.04.01 21:00:47.968,95.174,95.124,23.9,9.2
2007.04.01 21:01:02.695,95.132,95.092,4,4
2007.04.01 21:01:05.934,95.154,95.104,11.2,4
2007.04.01 21:01:18.430,95.171,95.131,12,5.2
2007.04.01 21:01:19.957,95.188,95.153,8,9.2
2007.04.01 21:01:56.308,95.208,95.148,22.3,4
2007.04.01 21:01:57.233,95.192,95.152,7.2,9.2
2007.04.01 21:01:57.443,95.188,95.143,7.2,9.2
2007.04.01 21:01:59.691,95.184,95.139,7.2,9.2
2007.04.01 21:01:59.934,95.181,95.141,8,3.9
2007.04.01 21:02:10.569,95.171,95.136,11.9,4
2007.04.01 21:02:20.708,95.166,95.126,11.2,8.8
2007.04.01 21:02:35.211,95.17,95.135,21.5,4
2007.04.01 21:02:39.946,95.196,95.156,7.2,8.8
2007.04.01 21:02:40.206,95.224,95.164,0.8,0.8
2007.04.01 21:02:43.600,95.222,95.177,8,9.2
2007.04.01 21:02:54.578,95.216,95.186,25.5,5.2
2007.04.01 21:03:04.811,95.23,95.18,7.9,7.9
```

all the way to last day of month.

I need to know the day whenever the percent change((max - min) / max) of Ask price of that day is greater than 0.05. My approach was to separate the data day by day, and calculate the percent change to see if the price drops more than 5% that day, and return that day if it does. I'm new to pandas and here's what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('AUDJPY_Ticks_2007.04.01_2007.04.30.csv')
percentChange = ((df['Ask'].max() - df['Ask'].min()) / df['Ask'].max()) >= 0.05
print(percentChange)
```

I can only get the percent change of the entire month instead of each day.

Comment: A first step is surely to [import your time as a datetime index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `index_col = "Time (UTC)", parse_dates = ["Time (UTC)"]`. And then you might want to look into [pandas rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A solution with `resample` and `transform`:

---

#### Data:

I modified your example data to simply allow for our test case to look at multiple days and so that at least one day has a change greater than 0.05%. Also, so the next person who reads this will have a copy-and-paste reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

test_data = StringIO("""Time (UTC),Ask,Bid,AskVolume,BidVolume
2007.04.01 21:00:47.593,95.203,95.159,19.1,8.8
2007.04.01 21:00:47.968,95.174,95.124,23.9,9.2
2007.04.01 21:01:02.695,95.132,95.092,4,4
2007.04.01 21:01:05.934,95.154,95.104,11.2,4
2007.04.02 21:01:18.430,95.171,95.131,12,5.2
2007.04.02 21:01:19.957,95.188,95.153,8,9.2
2007.04.02 21:01:56.308,95.208,95.148,22.3,4
2007.04.02 21:01:57.233,95.192,95.152,7.2,9.2
2007.04.03 21:01:57.443,91.188,95.143,7.2,9.2
2007.04.03 21:01:59.691,97.684,95.139,7.2,9.2 
2007.04.03 21:01:59.934,95.181,95.141,8,3.9
2007.04.03 21:02:10.569,95.171,95.136,11.9,4
2007.04.04 21:02:20.708,95.166,95.126,11.2,8.8
2007.04.04 21:02:35.211,95.17,95.135,21.5,4
2007.04.04 21:02:39.946,95.196,95.156,7.2,8.8
2007.04.04 21:02:40.206,95.224,95.164,0.8,0.8
2007.04.05 21:02:43.600,95.222,95.177,8,9.2
2007.04.05 21:02:54.578,95.216,95.186,25.5,5.2
2007.04.05 21:03:04.811,95.23,95.18,7.9,7.9""")

df = pd.read_table(test_data, sep=",", header=[0], parse_dates=["Time (UTC)"])
```

#### Set index to datetime column:

```
df.set_index("Time (UTC)", drop=True, inplace=True)
```

#### Resample and transform:

```
daily_ask = df.resample("D")["Ask"]
df["daily_ask_min"] = daily_ask.transform("min")
df["daily_ask_max"] = daily_ask.transform("max")
```

#### Calculate percent daily change:

```
df["daily_ask_change"] = (df["daily_ask_max"] - df["daily_ask_min"]) / df["daily_ask_max"]
```

#### Find changes greater than 0.05 % :

```
df[df.daily_ask_change > 0.05]["daily_ask_change"]

# Time (UTC)
# 2007-04-03 21:01:57.443    0.0665
# 2007-04-03 21:01:59.691    0.0665
# 2007-04-03 21:01:59.934    0.0665
# 2007-04-03 21:02:10.569    0.0665
# Name: daily_ask_change, dtype: float64


df[df.daily_ask_change > 0.05]["daily_ask_change"].resample("D").mean()

# Time (UTC)
# 2007-04-03    0.0665
# Freq: D, Name: daily_ask_change, dtype: float64
```